# How to remove mails from mail app and maintain google calendar synchronized with Apple Reminders?

Tags: mail.app, data-synchronization, gmail, google-calendar

I've got a gmail account and I use the browser to read, write and manage my gmail account.

I wrongly opened Apple mail and it started synchronizing with gmail.

I would like to maintain google calendar synchronized with Apple Reminders, but I would like to free the space on HD used by Apple mail.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try system preferences -> Internet accounts -> uncheck mail from google account

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bart, do you think that this solution will clean disk space?

Comment: It will stop safari from downloading any more of your emails, but I am not sure if it deletes emails that have already been downloaded. You can check how big your mail folder is by going to finder -> holding alt/option, clicking on "Go" tab and open "Library" -> scroll down and look for "Mail" -> you can right click and get info to see how big the folder is. I found this link about deleting files from mail folder, but maybe do a bit of research just to be safe [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24625/is-it-safe-to-remove-library-mail-folders) .